# Function which accepts a slice of tuples of slices with IntoIterator trait

Tags: rust

I have a function `f` which should be called like this:

```
struct S;

let s = &S;

f(&[(s, &[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (s, &[0.5, 0.6])]);
```

For a convenience interface, I want `f` to handle any kind of `IntoIterator`. At the moment, my signature is

```
fn f<'a, I, J: 'a>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a (&'a S, J)>,
    J: IntoIterator<Item = &'a f32>
```

sadly, the compiler treats the slices as fixed sized arrays, so I got this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> sandbox/src/main.rs:142:33
    |
142 |     f(&[(s, &[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (s, &[0.5, 0.6])]);
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 3 elements, found one with 2 elements
    |
    = note: expected type `&[{float}; 3]`
               found type `&[{float}; 2]`
```

Replacing `J` with `Vec<f32>` works, but this is isn't the way I want to go.

Is there a way to handle this so that I can call the function the way I mentioned? At first I thought this could be solved with [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), but these are only available for lifetime parameters.

If it can be made to work, how do I properly handle these nested `IntoIterator`? How I can call `J::into_iter()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function definition is perfectly fine; the problem is how you construct the argument. Without the function it does not work either:

```
41 |     let x = &[(s, &[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (s, &[0.5, 0.6])];
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 3 elements, found one with 2 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `&[{float}; 3]`
              found type `&[{float}; 2]`
```

The compiler sees the first element of the outer slice and infers that this slice has elements of type `(&S, &[{float}; 3])`. This conflicts with the second element which has length 2. It simply does not know that it could/should use the more generic arbitrary slice `&[{float}]`.

If we explicitly force the type of the first element it compiles fine:

```
f(&[(s, &[0.1f32, 0.2, 0.3] as &[f32]), (s, &[0.5, 0.6])]);
```

Alternatively, you can pass in iterators, which conveniently also implement `IntoIterator`:

```
f(&[(s, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3].iter()), (s, [0.5, 0.6].iter())]);
```

Granted, neither approach is particularly convenient (although the latter is not too bad IMO). If the goal is to have a function that takes nested slices you can define it as such:

```
fn f2<T>(iter: &[(&S, &[T])]) {}

f2(&[(s, &[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), (s, &[0.5, 0.6])]);
```

You have to choose your trade-off: Either have a function that conveniently takes slices but refuses other iterables, or have a function that takes any iterable but is slightly more cumbersome to invoke.

This advice also applies if your function uses the new `impl Trait`-syntax:

```
fn f<'a>(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a (&'a S, impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a f32> + 'a)>)
```

Comment: Makes sense. I will go with the first approach and stick to my signature, since the iterator is more generic.

Comment: @Tim there *may* be other ways; I'm not too much of an expert here. But since there was no response in three hours I decided to share what little I know :) I suggest you check back tomorrow or so... someone else might know a way that lets you have both.